# Can two raspberry pi zeros communicate through the hdmi port?

Tags: pi-zero, cluster

I want to cluster a bunch of raspberry pi zeros together through their hdmi ports since that port seems to be the only one that can handle 8megapixels worth of data at 60 FPS but from what I’ve read about hdmi on the raspberry pi zeros is that it is only used as a way to connect to monitors. Is there a way to use two way communication on the hdmi port?

Comment: even a 300 baud serial link can handle `8 megapixels worth of data`

Comment: 8 megapixels every 1/60th a second

Comment: HDMI ports are output only (like 99.99% of computers).

Comment: 8megapixels not 8 pi zeros. Also I want parallel cpus and raspberry pi 4 is not $5.

Comment: the pi0 doesn't handle 4k60hz os, it does not do 8 megapixels every 1/60th second - anyway, how much data is 8megapixel per 1/0th second?

Comment: Why use HDMI for communication of all interfaces available on the Pi? HDMI is point to point only, so there's no chance to use it for any kind of networking.

Comment: My plan was to have multiple pi zeros listen and divide the 60fps into more manageable chunks.

Comment: I didn’t know that it was only point to point. All I knew I that hdmi is faster than the usb 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because:

- HDMI on the pi is output only; there are data input paths in HDMI (CEC), but they are low data rate
- HDMI on the pi goes through a video module, and can't transmit general purpose data
- pi zero may be (marginally?) too slow to handle this data rate, even if it is video

If you want to do networking, why not use the network on the pi?
You can either use the wifi, or solder a rj45 network jack on it.

You say your motivation for using the pi zero is that it is $5.  However, you need to realize that the reason it is so cheap is that it is a minimal device, and is much slower than other more expensive versions of the pi, and may not be able to do what you want because of that.

Comment: I read that the raspberry pi 4 has 4 cores that run at 1.4 ghz. If use 5-6 raspberry pi zeros in parallel (which are 1 core at 1ghz), won’t it get close to the same speed? 1.4*4=5.6

Comment: No.  The pi 4 has a different generation cpu, and you can't compare cpu speed between generations by looking at the cpu clock as other optimizations in addition to clock speed make it faster.  It doesn't add up that way even if they were the same generation.  And the pi zero takes shortcuts to make it cheaper that make it slower.  The pi 4 takes much fewer such shortcuts.

Comment: If you have a buggy that is pulled with one horse, would you expect it to go 4 times faster with 4 horses?

Comment: How can i compare speeds then? Is there a number I can look up that will tell me how fast a cpu completes instructions?

Comment: It's called benchmarks.  And they are notoriously unreliable for comparing speeds as well.  The best way to compare speeds is to run the same application (that you care about) on both processors and measure the speed.  With a generic benchmark, at best, you can guess.